# Does `dlopen()` performs dynamic linking by invoking dynamic linker `ld-linux.so`?

Tags: dynamic-linking, ld

CSAPP says

> Linux systems provide a simple interface to **the dynamic linker** that allows
> application programs to load and link shared libraries at run time.
>
> ```
> #include <dlfcn.h>
> void *dlopen(const char *filename, int flag);
> ```
>
> Returns: pointer to handle if OK, NULL on error

Does `dlopen()` performs dynamic linking by invoking dynamic linker `ld-linux.so`?

Is     `ld-linux.so` the dynamic linker which `dlopen()` invokes to perform dynamic linking?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dlopen` is provided by `libdl`, but behind the scenes, with the GNU C library implementation at least, the latter relies on symbols provided by `ld-linux.so` to perform the dynamic linking. If `dlopen` is called from a dynamically-linked program, `ld-linux.so` is already loaded, so it uses those symbols directly; if it’s called from a statically-linked program, it tries to load `ld-linux.so`.

Comment: Admitted the question was very poor, but this answer could still be a little more precise. `dlopen` does not "invoke" `ld-linux.so` in any way -- if you call `dlopen` from a static executable, it will (try to) open and load `ld-linux.so` (as yet another dynamic object) in order to use the functions defined within it. With a dynamic executable, `ld-linux.so` is already in the memory of the process -- `dlopen` doesn't even have to load it, it just calls into it.

Comment: @user414777 thanks for the extra information. I don’t think I wrote that `dlopen` “invokes” `ld-linux.so`, did I? I wrote that it relies on `dl-linux.so`, which is true in either case. I’ll rephrase to make it clearer.

Comment: The OP did, suggesting that dlopen somehow executes ld.so. Maybe it was just awkward phrasing, but my impression was that the OP's question (and other question of the same series) are somehow leading, trying to extract ridiculous generalities. I hope I'm wrong. Wrt another answer of yours, notice that an ELF executable does not need an entry point; Linux will ignore its entry point if its program header table has a PT_INTERP entry.

Comment: Right, I take it you’re not familiar with Tim’s style of questions ;-). AIUI Linux doesn’t ignore the entry point, it passes it to the interpreter in the execution attributes, doesn’t it?

Comment: Yes, by "ignore" I was meaning that the Linux kernel would not care about it, it can have any value as long as the ELF points to an interpreter. And then the interpreter may not care about it either.

Comment: It can have any value but the kernel still doesn’t ignore it entirely; it adjusts it by the load bias, which the interpreter needs to know about. (And yes, the interpreter can look for `_start`, but on Linux it doesn’t if an `AT_ENTRY` entry is present.)

Comment: The interpreter can do anything afterwards. The interpreter can be any self-contained executable, not just `ld.so`. My point was that **a.** an executable ELF file in Linux is a file which starts with `\x7fELF` which, when is passed as argument to `execve(2)` will not cause it to return with an error and **b** such a file doesn't necessarily need to have any valid entry point (as you were claiming). The Linux kernel is not an ELF validator, you can create tiny "dynamically linked" binaries (shorter than the size of the ELF header), which contain not much more than the path to an intepreter.

Comment: Of course the interpreter can do anything afterwards, and I am familiar with teensy and other such ELF experiments. However the kernel does check [a little more than the first four bytes](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8.12/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L820) ;-). But while it’s possible to create arbitrary pairs of ELF binaries and interpreters that will do *something*, that doesn’t really help understand how ELF binaries are supposed to work. The spec calls for an entry point, and that’s where execution starts in spec-compliant binaries (and interpreters).

Comment: "the kernel does check a little more than the first four bytes" Yes, about two dozen or so of them ;-) I'll post an example when I have a better device to type on. As to the interpreter, it only has to be compliant with the programs which call it.